# Absolute and conditional convergence example problem. Since pi cannot be represented as a fraction, is this reasoning correct or incorrect?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

The example problem sought to find whether

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{sin(n)}{n^2}$$

is conditionally convergent, absolutely convergent, or divergent.

It attempted to prove convergence by using the comparison test and the p-series test to bound $\dfrac{sin(n)}{n^2}$ from above.

$\dfrac{1}{n^2} \ge \dfrac{sin(n)}{n^2} \ge -\dfrac{1}{n^2} $

However, I began to wonder whether this notation was correct. $sin(n)$ only equals $1$ for $n = \pi/2$. However, we cannot represent $\pi$ as a fraction, since it is an irrational number. Therefore, wouldn't $\dfrac{1}{n^2} \ge \dfrac{sin(n)}{n^2} \ge -\dfrac{1}{n^2}$
 be false? Wouldn't it instead  be true that $\dfrac{1}{n^2} > \dfrac{sin(n)}{n^2} > -\dfrac{1}{n^2} $?

Please check my reasoning. If my reasoning is incorrect, please clarify why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequalities are flipped around, they should be

$$-\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{\sin n}{n^2}<\frac1{n^2}.$$

And, yes, the strict inequality is correct, but $\leq$ is not incorrect. Since, if $a<b$ is true, then $a\leq b$ is **also** true.

Also, for absolute convergence, you don't need the two inequalities, since you can take $\frac{|\sin n|}{n^2}$ and just bound this with $\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: I made an error. I will edit it now. My apologies.

Comment: if $a < b$ is true, then how can $a \le b$ also always be true? That does not seem logically correct to me.

Comment: @ThePointer $a\leq b$ is true if $a<b$ **or** $a= b$. For example, $3\leq 4$ is true because $3<4$ is true. $3\leq 3$ is true because $3=3$ is true.

Remember, $a\leq b$ means "$a$ is *less than or equal to* $b$".

Comment: I forgot that in mathematics, we do not use the 'exclusive or'. Its like with unions in linear algebra, right? In mathematics, $a$ or $b$ can be $a$, $b$, or both?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes, but that's not the point. $a<b$ and $a=b$ **are** mutually exclusive. However, $a<b$ and $a\leq b$ are not. In fact, the relation $<$ is a strict subset of $\leq$, i.e. if $a<b$, then $a\leq b$ (while the reverse is *not* true).

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you very much. Please leave your comments undeleted so that I may reference them again in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Remember that  absolutely convergence implies convergence. Moroever
$$\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
and we can use the comparison test (which can not be applied  to $\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}$ because its sign is not eventually constant).

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The comparison test has the condition that $0 \le a_n \le b_n$. Thank you.